# How to make xinput change permanent?

Tags: xinput

My Laptop's touchpad was not clicking on taping.
so i searched for google, and found that on running this

```
xinput --set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" 272 1
```

(272 is "Tapping Enabled")
it started working. But the [article](https://linuxhint.com/change_mouse_touchpad_settings_xinput_linux/) which i was reading said that it won't be parmanent.
So i created this file named `99-libinput.conf` and puted it in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`
, saved it and rebooted my laptop but it still didn't worked.

`99-libinput.config` file

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "My Touchpad"
MatchProduct "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
Option "TappingEnabled" "true"
EndSection
```

Help me figure out where i have messed up

Comment: Let's start with your Ubuntu version.

Comment: @Pilot6 Lubuntu (20.04.5 LTS x86_64)

Comment: Is `libinput` used there?

Comment: yeah. Driver 'libinput"

Comment: So my answer should be good. You made a file in a wrong place with a wrong content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139729/discussion-between-ajcky-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu or Lubuntu you are doing all wrong.

There is a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

The tapping is enabled in the touchpad section this way:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "True"
EndSection
```

You can also enable tapping in mouse settings GUI.